# Links in archive not including taxonomy parameter

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, urls

I've created a custom content that can belong to several categories: status, age and specie. For now there are only the following terms for these taxonomies:

- species: dogs, cats
- age: adult, young, old
- status: in adoption

I am always encountering the same problem with the resolution of the url of the links in the different pages, I suppose because of not using hierarchical taxonomies or not rewriting the urls.
For example, on the "archive" page, if I use the url "/?post_type=rescued&specie=dog", each post shows a link but does not include the taxonomy, from what I have seen in the parent theme the function is used get_permalink.

Is there a function or configuration that can help me with that or will I have to override the url creation on each page in my child theme?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using a CPT plugin to create these taxonomies?

Comment: @WhisparDesign no, im using registre function.